# Why can't I VTC this as duplicate? It has an upvoted+accepted answer

Tags: bug, status-completed, duplicates, vote-to-close

Look at [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/250282/unable-to-install-the-ubuntu-toolkit). I bumped into it using the Review Queue for Close Votes. I agree with the proposed duplicate, but I am unable to vote-to-close it:

[image]

The error **This question does not have an upvoted or accepted answer** is simply not true. [The duplicate question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/236012/cant-install-qt-components-ubuntu-because-im-using-full-release-of-qt-5-0-0) involved has an accepted answer with a score of 5:

[image]

---

I believe this is a bug in the new build just being deployed. Please fix this.

Comment: 5 minutes after posting this, @Seth told me about this on MSO: [bug in closing duplicate question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/165921/195914). So it seems an SE-wide problem.

Comment: But I don't think it is duplicate question

Comment: @Tachyons Post that as a comment to the question involved. Not relevant here.

Comment: Sorry for the inconvenience - should work properly now.